# Legend with name of y variable and not only treatment

Tags: python, legend

I am doing a 2-y axis plot with sns in python. I get a legend reporting the two treatments in my data set, but I don't get the name of the  y label in the legend. Thank you in advance.

The example of data frame is:

```
Obs / sampling time /replicate / y1 /  y2
1        midday        1          8   9     
2        midday        1          8.5 9.5
1        evening       2          4   5
2        evening       2          4.5 5
```

[The legend repeats twice treatment and y label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDaru.png)

This is how my code looks like:

```
sns.lineplot(x="Obs", y="y1",
             hue="sampling time", style="sampling time", ci=95, markers=True, color="red",
             dashes=False, legend="full", label = "y1", data=df)
ax.set_xlabel('time (min)', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('y1', fontsize=14, color="red")

ax2 = ax.twinx()

sns.lineplot(x="Obs", y="y2", hue="sampling time", style="sampling time", color="blue", markers=True,
                    legend ="full", ci=95, labels= "Ci", data=df)

ax2.set_ylabel('y2', fontsize=14, color="blue")

ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you give an example of `df` in `data=df`?

Comment: Long time no response, I hope you can try to set `label` value in each lineplot, like `sns.lineplot(x="Obs", y="Ci", hue="sampling time", style="sampling time", color="blue", markers=True, legend ="full", ci=95, data=df, label="Ci")`.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, thank you for your comment. I implemented your suggestion and I share the output. I will also add example of dataframe.